# Rewriting a URL in an RSS feed for autoblogged

Tags: url-rewriting, rss, autoblogged

I pull images from my Pinterest feed to put on my photography blog. The rss address of my board is http://pinterest.com/bokehphotos/test/rss

If you stick that in a rss validator (http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3a%2f%2fpinterest.com%2fbokehphotos%2ftest%2frss), you'll see that the img scrs you get all end in _b.jpg, like this: "media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com/upload/80290805828015284_SNRmbshz_b.jpg"

Change that _b to a _c, like this media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com/upload/80290805828015284_SNRmbshz_c.jpg, and you get the full size image, rather than the thumbnail with the _b.jpg

What I need to do is rewrite the URL in the feed before autoblogged grabs it.

I can add custom values and custom fields, and also do a search and replace on the feed using regular expression.

The only thing I have managed to do so far is change the name of the file autoblogged uploads from ending in b.jpg to c.jpg, but not the actual url in the feed!

I have been pulling my hair out over this for nearly two days now, and any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks very much,
Leo

Answer (score 2):

Leo, have you investigated Yahoo Pipes? Quite a lot of tutorials on Youtube... sorry I can't be specific but I've used it in the past to achieve similar feed rewrites.

Comment: Never heard of Yahoo Pipes before, but by god am I glad I do now! You are a true genius. I can't thank you enough, seriously, I've been butting my head against the wall on this for almost 2 days, like I said...Now it's working. My only niggle is that I now need to figure out how to use the regular expression in autoblogged, rather than using the feed I generate through Yahoo Pipes. But the fact remains that I've now got the functionality I was after. Thank you again.

Comment: Should flag this as an answer, if it worked for you. Just check the mark under the up/down vote to the left.